# Objective-c: Copying a Directory to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to copy an entire folder content to another folder i create, using Objective-c on iOS.

I have tried doing that using NSFileManager to create and copy the directory with an UIAlertView to check the error:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:@"/tmp/Destination/Directory/" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];

NSError *copyError = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:@"/Source/Directory/ toPath:@"/tmp/Destination/Directory/" error:&copyError]) {

    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Watusi" message:[copyError description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

The code is not working and i am getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomainCode=516 "The operation coulnd't be completed. 
(Cocoas error 516.)" Userinfo=0x1666db90 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Source/Directory/, NSUserStringVariant=(Copy),
NSFilePath=/Source/Directory/,NSDestionationFilePath=/tmp/Destination/Directory/, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x14697b30 "The Operation couldn't be completed. File Exists"}
```

Actually the directory is getting created but the files are not being copied to it

I have checked every question related to my issue but wasn't able to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error was so obvious in `"The Operation couldn't be completed. File Exists"`

the folder `Directory` at `toPath:@"/tmp/Destination/Directory/"` will be automatically created,

I was creating it manually in `createDirectoryAtPath:@"/tmp/Destination/Directory/"` which is wrong

so the fixed code is:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:@"/tmp/Destination/" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];

NSError *copyError = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:@"/Source/Directory/" toPath:@"/tmp/Destination/Directory/" error:&copyError]) {

    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:[copyError description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

NOTE: the code works to copy a directory and its subdirectories

Answer (score 4):

You need to *create destination directory and then enumerate all files inside source directory and copy them to destination*.

Subdirectories will complicate things a bit. If you have them, your enumeration code should be **recursive**.

**UDATE:**

Here is the code sample. Please note, that it doesn't handle subdirectories.

```
NSString *sourcePath = @"...";
NSString *destPath = @"...";
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[fm createDirectoryAtPath:destPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];

NSArray *sourceFiles = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:NULL];
NSError *copyError = nil;

BOOL isDirectory;

for (NSString *currentFile in sourceFiles)
{
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:currentFile isDirectory:&isDirectory] && !isDirectory)
    {
        if (![fm copyItemAtPath:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFile] toPath:[destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFile] error:&copyError])
        {
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Watusi" message:[copyError description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, instead of showing error after each unsuccessful copy operation, I'd create a mutable array, where I'd add file names that failed to copy and then show them to the user the loop.

Comment: As i mentioned, I am creating the destination directory with `createDirectoryAtPath:` May i have a little example on how to enumerate and copy the files, please?

Comment: Hey! i appreciate your help but this code didn't even work to copy 1 folder content :/ and i actually need to copy its subdirectories as well.

Comment: How do you create your source directory in Xcode project?

Comment: ([fm fileExistsAtPath:currentFile isDirectory:&isDirectory] && !isDirectory) will return false!

Comment: The code as it exists in the answer will not work. The `fileExistsAtPath` needs to have the `sourcePath` prepended to the `currentFile` for it to work.